# How to use different models in one View and pass the value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have one View from where I need to pass the `Id_cliente` to controller.

This is my Model:

```
 public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Azienda")]
        public string Nome_azienda { get; set; }
    }

 public class SottoCliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Id_cliente { get; set; }
    }
```

In my View by clicking on the button Sotto Clienti I need to pass the `Id_cliente` from Model `SottoCliente` to controller. I don't know how to access the `Id_cliente`. This is my View :

```
@model IEnumerable<GestioneAtivita.Models.Cliente>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               ...
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cognome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_azienda)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cellulare)
            </td>
            <td>
                //Here I have button, and here I need somthing like  new { clienteId = item.`Id_cliente`} to pass Id_cliente to controller
                @Html.ActionLink("Sotto Clienti", "CaricaSottoCliente", new { clienteId = item.Id}, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
            <td> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Modifica", "ModificaCliente", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Elimina", "EliminaCliente", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And CaricaSottoCliente is the action where I'm trying to load the records from database based on Id_cliente :

```
public ActionResult CaricaSottoCliente(int clienteId)
    {
        if (clienteId == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        SottoCliente sottoCliente = _db.tboSottoClienti
            .Include(a => a.Nome)
            .Where(a => a.Id == clienteId)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (sottoCliente == null)
        {
            return  RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var view = new ViewModels
        {
            Id = sottoCliente.Id,
            Nome = sottoCliente.Nome,
            //ListaSottoClientis = sottoCliente.getCliente.ToList()
        };
        return View(view);
```

Everything works fine, but I don't get Id_cliente , instead I get the Id from Client Model.

Any ideas how to pass the Id_cliente to the controller?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class like this.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public SottoCliente SottoCliente { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Azienda")]
    public string Nome_azienda { get; set; }
}

public class SottoCliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_cliente { get; set; }
}
```

And in model declare like this `@model IEnumerable<GestioneAtivita.Models.Parent>` and use the properties accordingly.

Comment: I can't use `@model IEnumerable<GestioneAtivita.Models.Parent>` it gives me error: **The 'model' directive may only occur once per document.**

Comment: remove this like also `@model IEnumerable<GestioneAtivita.Models.Cliente>`

Comment: If I remove that I can't access :  `item.Nome` `item.Cognome` `item.Nome_azienda` ...

Comment: try `item.Cliente.Nome`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ViewModel that contains both the classes SottoCliente and  Cliente.

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public SottoCliente SottoCliente { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Azienda")]
    public string Nome_azienda { get; set; }
}

public class SottoCliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_cliente { get; set; }
}
```

In the View access the fields like this

```
@model IEnumerable<GestioneAtivita.Models.ClientViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               ...
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente.Cognome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente.Nome_azienda)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente.Cellulare)
            </td>
            <td>
                //Here I have button, and here I need somthing like  new { clienteId = item.`Id_cliente`} to pass Id_cliente to controller
                @Html.ActionLink("Sotto Clienti", "CaricaSottoCliente", new { clienteId = item.SottoCliente.Id}, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
            <td> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Modifica", "ModificaCliente", new { id = item.Cliente.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Elimina", "EliminaCliente", new { id = item.Cliente.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It gives me error:  **InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GestioneAtivita.Models.Cliente]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GestioneAtivita.Models.ClientViewModel]'.**

Comment: Can you please provide the code on how you retuning the data to view ??

Comment: I just update my question. I changed the action who load items from bd based on `SottoCliente.Id`